# JSP search database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, search

Scenario 1: User wants to find the admin, who's name is jan. He types in 'admin jan' or 'jan admin'. Then the result should be: if there is a user with 'jan' AND 'admin' in the database, that it will show that user. Even if there are 10 others with 'jan' AND 'admin' for example in their e-mail, or street name or whatever, it should show them too. 
Scenario 2: User wants to find someone named 'bebe' with the skills 'HQL PHP bebe SQL JAVA'. It should show every user with these words in the database. So it should only show users with those skills and name, so if someone else doesn't have the skill HQL, but does have the skill PHP SQL JAVA, don't show this one.

What I have only searches the last word. So if I search for 'THIS THAT THOSE PHP SQL ADMIN' it only finds everyone with ADMIN and ignores the rest of the String.

```
if (action.equals("searchUser")) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    String searchQuery = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
    String[] query = searchQuery.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
        String hql = "FROM User WHERE username LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%' OR firstname LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%' OR lastname LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%' OR emailAddress LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%'";

        List<User> result = session.createQuery(hql).list();
        //set our results on the request and redirect back
        request.setAttribute("users", result);
        request.setAttribute("usersSize", result.size());
        request.setAttribute("usersSizeResults", result.size());

        System.out.println("size:" + result.size());
    }
    redirect(request, response, "/search.jsp");
    session.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to avoid duplicated values  (*NOT TESTED*):

```
public void searchUser() {
if (action.equals("searchUser")) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    String searchQuery = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
    String[] params = searchQuery.split(" ");

    // Found users
    List<User> usersFound = new ArrayList<User>();

    // Exact match
    String hqlMatch = this.getSearchHqlQuery(params, "AND");
    List<User> exactResult = session.createQuery(hqlMatch).list();
    if (exactResult!=null && !exactResult.isEmpty()) {
        usersFound.addAll(exactResult);
    }
    // Multiple search
    else {
        String hqlLike = this.getSearchHqlQuery(params, "OR");
        List<User> likeResult = session.createQuery(hqlLike).list();
        if (likeResult!=null && !likeResult.isEmpty()) {
            usersFound.addAll(likeResult);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("size:" + usersFound.size());
        // set our results on the request and redirect back
        request.setAttribute("users", usersFound);
        request.setAttribute("usersSize", usersFound.size());
        request.setAttribute("usersSizeResults", usersFound.size());

        redirect(request, response, "/search.jsp");
        session.close();
    }
}

private String getSearchHqlQuery(String[] params, String andOrfilter) {
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
    hql.append("from User ");
    if (params.length > 0) {
        hql.append("where ");
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) { hql.append(andOrfilter); }
            hql.append(" (username like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%' OR firstname like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%' OR lastname like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%' OR emailAddress like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%') ");
        }
    }
    return hql.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick! This is really advanced and difficult haha

Comment: Thanks again for the code, it works great, but maybe you can help with this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406778/jsp-search-in-more-tables-in-database
?
Because you have created the code, and know so much about this, maybe you can also help with that? Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

HQL is case sensitive for java class attributes used. Are the username and firstname exactly declared as this in the User class?

May be instead:

```
"FROM User WHERE (userName LIKE '%jan%' OR firstName LIKE '%jan%' OR lastName LIKE '%jan%' OR emailAddress LIKE '%jan%')"
```

Be careful on your foreach loop: you make a query for each parameter of the list. And you send only the last result in the response. Is that right??

May be instead:

```
    if (action.equals("searchUser")) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String searchQuery = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
        String[] query = searchQuery.split(" ");

        List<User> usersFound = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (int i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
            String hql = "FROM User WHERE username LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%' OR firstname LIKE '%" + query[i]
                    + "%' OR lastname LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%' OR emailAddress LIKE '%" + query[i] + "%'";
            List<User> result = session.createQuery(hql).list();
            if (result != null) {
                usersFound.addAll(result);
                System.out.println("size:" + result.size());
            }
        }

        // set our results on the request and redirect back
        request.setAttribute("users", usersFound);
        request.setAttribute("usersSize", usersFound.size());
        request.setAttribute("usersSizeResults", usersFound.size());

        redirect(request, response, "/search.jsp");
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: Your first post, was unclear, but your updated post, is my answer. Thanks it works great. It finds every one I put in the input search field

Comment: One problem.. If Jan is also Admin, and I search for Jan admin, it shows jan twice. Can I exclude double results of one user?

Comment: I edited my post. The foreach is your problem: you might extract the request.setAttribute() from the loop. About case sentitive, it was about class attributes such as 'username' or 'lastname'. But if your query works well, no matter the case.

Comment: This searches for multiple words, but there are two problems; 
`user1: name= jan, username= admin` and  `user2: name= bebe, username = admin`. Problem one is, if I search for jan admin, it shows jan twice in the results. Problem two is, if I search for jan admin, I only want jan admin to show up, no bebe admin

Comment: Is there a fix for this?

Comment: i think it can be done in one query, to avoid duplicates. But it complicates a bit: where clause can be built in the loop, and one query executed at the end. It requires more reflexion. Is 'distinct' allowed in HQL ? In the worst case (if you are allergic to HQL or SQL), you can manage this in java after the requests, but this is clearly not the best option.

Comment: I am new to all this HQL, jsp and Java stuff...... I have no clue if it is allowed...

Comment: But if my search query contains every word that the user bebe has, for example; bebe horea oop hotmail com, it shows bebe 5 times in the results now, that's really not good....