# JSP search in more tables in database

Tags: java, sql, jsp

With this search.jsp, it finds matches all words searched by user, then removes duplicate found users and shows a list of found matches.

I can only search for e-mail, firstname, lastname, username of a user, but I also want to search skills, and show the users who match that skill found.

> For example I search for username; Admin, it finds the admin and shows
>   this person in the result. This works now, but I also want this;;; If
>   I search for Java, Then I want everybody that has the skill Java to 
>   show up in the result.

I know it is easier with SQL query's, but this is different. 
I have provided the models and database information below;

database:

```
**Table name: User**
userId
emailAddress
firstname
lastname
username

**Table name: user_skill**
User_userId
skills_skillId

**Table name: skill**
skillId
name
```

where it all happens : : : search.jsp:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Hij komt er in");

    //get the action
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    String action = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

    if (action.equals("searchUser")) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String searchQuery = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
        String[] params = searchQuery.split(" ");

        // Found users
        List<User> usersFound = new ArrayList<User>();

        // Exact match
        String hqlMatch = this.getSearchHqlQuery(params, "AND");
        List<User> exactResult = session.createQuery(hqlMatch).list();
        if (exactResult != null && !exactResult.isEmpty()) {
            usersFound.addAll(exactResult);
        } // Multiple search
        else {
            String hqlLike = this.getSearchHqlQuery(params, "OR");
            List<User> likeResult = session.createQuery(hqlLike).list();
            if (likeResult != null && !likeResult.isEmpty()) {
                usersFound.addAll(likeResult);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("size:" + usersFound.size());
        // set our results on the request and redirect back
        request.setAttribute("users", usersFound);
        request.setAttribute("usersSize", usersFound.size());
        request.setAttribute("usersSizeResults", usersFound.size());

        redirect(request, response, "/search.jsp");
        session.close();
    }
}

private String getSearchHqlQuery(String[] params, String andOrfilter) {
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
    hql.append("from User ");
    if (params.length > 0) {
        hql.append("where ");
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                hql.append(andOrfilter);
            }
            hql.append(" (username like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%' OR firstname like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%' OR lastname like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%' OR emailAddress like '%").append(params[i]);
            hql.append("%') ");
        }
    }
    return hql.toString();
}
```

model.user.java:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int userId;
    private String username, firstname, lastname, emailAddress, position, password;
    private String fullName;
    private boolean isAdmin;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Skill> skills;

    public User(){

    }
```

model.skill.java:

```
@Entity
public class Skill implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private long skillId;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(25)")
    private String name;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(25)")
    private String level;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(250)")
    private String description;

    public Skill() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a join to the skills, and an or clause to your query:

```
select distinct u from User u
left join u.skills skill
where ... (existing or clauses)
or skill.name like :param
```

Also, your code is opened to SQL injection attacks, and will fail if the param contains a single quote. Use a named parameter as shown above.

Comment: The above is an example of how the query should look like. You're not supposed to copy and paste anything from my answer. There is a single place where you compose an HQL query in your code. So you should add the join, and the additional where clause, to this query. Take some time to read the HQL documentation to understand how joins work.

Comment: Try to understand the code using debug mode. You'll see how the query is built step by step and where you should add the 'left join' part. And JB is right, the query is not secured. You must use query.setParameter() to secure each param. See there for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251491/using-hibernate-named-parameter-twice.